# How to simplify db_restore

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

My current process for copying my database to the new server is to `pg_dump` with `--no-owner --no-privileges`

Then on the new server, I

1. create the database
2. create the two users
3. create all the necessary permissions for both users
4. run `pg_restore` as one user
5. change ownership of the objects that should be owned by the second user

This is a very tedious and error-prone process. Just a few minutes ago, for example, I have created all the objects in the postgres database, instead of mydatabase.

Is there a way to make it simpler? Can the dump contain all the users I need, all the permissions, and database name?

Is is possible to do it all with one `pg_dump` line on the main server, then `scp`, and the one `pg_restore` line on the new server?

Should I be using `pg_dumpall` instead? I have only one database on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pg_dumpall -r` to dump the users (roles).

Apart from that, I would say that scripting is a solution. Write a script that does all the right moves, so you don't have to do them by hand.

Comment: If I do dumpall, how do I restore?

Comment: Using `psql`. But `pg_dumpall -r` can be restored with any client.